# What is LEGO MINDSTORMS?

Tags: mindstorms

I have heard of LEGO MINDSTORMS, and wondered what it is for the longest time. What is it? What can you do with it?

Comment: LEGO's website for Mindstorms is well designed and a perfect stating point (http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms).  Since this information is readily available on the Web through minimal research, I recommend browsing the Stack Exchange Help section to better understand the format of this site (http://bricks.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: We also set up a reasonable intro on our [tag wiki page](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/tags/mindstorms/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LEGO MINDSTORMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms) is the brand name for a series of robotic toys produced by the LEGO Systems A/S.

The kits are centered around a programmable brick - a micro controller in a LEGO compatible housing that can be integrated LEGO products.

The kits include software that allow the user to write programs to command the brick to control motors and read data from sensors attached to the programmable brick. In other words, you can use it to create interactive LEGO models.

With some imagination and determination, you can do just about anything with it. Do a web search and you will find more examples of what other have done with their MINDSTORMS than I could possibly list.